# Bootstrap datepicker query?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two dates i.e `date` and `date1`. On `date`, I am getting month and year and on `date1`, I want to get the days of the specific month that was selected in `date`. The problem is that I am not able to achieve this. 
I have made fiddle example if anyone can help me out.

Please find the fiddle link in comment below.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sherazakbar/f2zfcdLz/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I can select a month and year on `datepicker`. On `datepicker1`, I can only choose the days of the corresponding month.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" />
<button id="resetBtn" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Clear</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
// Create the first datepicker based on month
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-yyyy',
    viewMode: 'months',
    minViewMode: 'months'
});

// On change, set the date of the first datepicker to the inputDate variable
// and then set the month on the second datepicker
$('#datepicker').on('change', function () {
    var inputDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var lastDate = new Date(inputDate.getFullYear(), inputDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        startDate: inputDate,
        endDate: lastDate
    });
});

// Reset the values for both datepickers
$('#resetBtn').click(function () {
    $('#datepicker').val("").datepicker('update');
    $('#datepicker1').val("").datepicker('update');
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker('remove');
});
```

*WARNING:*
This code will not be able to change the date selected from `datepicker` on `datepicker1` dynamically. You will need to clear the values using the `resetBtn` button as a workaround. You may need to add some error-handling on when the user tries to change the month on `datepicker` without first clearing the datepickers.

---

**UPDATE FROM OP:**
I have made a solution according to the requirement and there is no need of a clear button.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'MM',
    viewMode: 'months',
    minViewMode: 'months',    
});

$('#datepicker').on('focus', function () { 
    $('#datepicker1').val("").datepicker('update');
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker('remove');
}); 

$('#datepicker').on('change', function () {
    var inputDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var lastDate = new Date(inputDate.getFullYear(), inputDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        startDate: inputDate,
        endDate: lastDate,
        format: "dd",
        viewMode: "days",
        minViewMode: "days"
    });  
});
```

Comment: Yeah it helped but user can change datepicker1, my requirement is once month is selected in datepicker the same month days appear in datepicker1.